# Reaching Credit Limit

Tags: credit-card

What happens if you reach your credit limit? Would I have to cancel the card? I got a message saying that I am approaching my credit limit.

Comment: Hi Creditguy and welcome to the site.  Don't forget to edit your question with further clarifications if you need further info (like you indicate in the comments below), and to accept the answer when you feel it has been satisfactorily answered.  Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 3):

You won't have to cancel the card. However, you won't be able to make any new purchases on the card until you pay it down under the limit. Also, if you exceed the limit the credit card company may charge you additional fees.

Comment: So a credit limit is not a one time thing? If I have a credit limit of $1000 for example, would that mean that if I spend $100 for 10 days and pay it off I would still reach the credit limit?

Comment: The limit is the maximum you can borrow at any given time. If you pay off part or all of the debt, you can then borrow it again.

Comment: @creditguy21 credit cards are revolving debt, meaning that you can reach the limit an infinite number of times over and over again. If you pay it off, you'll immediately have that much available

Answer (score 0):

A credit card has a credit limit. The card issuer has extended you a line of credit (a loan), that you are allowed to use to make purchases. The card (loan) has a limit, and when you have reached that limit, you will not be allowed to spend more money (on the card, against that limit).

But since this loan is a 'revolving' loan, you can pay back part of the loan, and the car issuer will allow you to spend more (again, up to the limit). It is very similar to depositing money into a bank account (with a debit card). You can spend against that account until you reach the limit (the account reaches zero), and then you can deposit more funds, and then use those funds (ad infinitum). The difference is that it is a loan, so you did not deposit the initial amount, you were granted a variable sized loan that can grow up to a specified amount (the credit limit).

Given an initial limit of $1000, you could spend $100/day for 10 days, reach your limit, and then send a $500 payment, and spend $100/day for another 5 days, (repeat). And then send a $1000 payment, and have the $1000 limit available.

However, caution is advised.  Should you choose to use more than 20%-30% of your credit limit, your credit utilization (ratio, percentage) will be reported to the credit bureaus as high (10% is best, 20% good, 30% ok, higher is bad), and will reflect as a negative mark on your credit report, reducing your credit score.  A good rule of thumb is to keep your utilization ratio under 30% (20% is even better, some suggest 10% is best). The warning you received that you are approaching your credit limit suggests that you are using a large percentage of your limit, and thus adversely affecting (lowering) your credit score.

Since credit cards are unsecured loans, you may find that the interest rate charged is higher than the interest rate charged for home or auto loans.